# Как отключить кеширование jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css

Проблема такая, подключил на example.php framework (css, js)
при переходе с этой страницы на любую другую этот фреймворк продолжает работать, хотя на тех страницах он не подключен, коверкает мне все стили
но после обновления страницы в Firebug соответственно пропадают все включения в страницу этого пакета, и страница отображается корректно

Как победить это?

Comment: какой фреймворк Вы используете? если он не подключен, его css и js не будут использоваться

Comment: jquerymobile, он подключен лишь на одной странице, но при переходе с нее на другие в firebug видно все <link.. но при обновлении страницы они пропадают

Comment: можете дать ссылку на Ваш сайт или на любую страницу где мы можем воспроизвести Вашу проблему?